# Relationship Between Chi-Square/Gamma & t/lst distributions?

Tags: distributions, gamma-distribution, t-distribution, chi-squared-distribution, location-scale-family

I'm trying to understand $\chi^2_n$ & $\Gamma(\theta, k)$ distributions. Currently I believe they're comparable to [t](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution) (aka $t_v$) & [location-scale-t](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution) (aka $lst(\mu, \sigma^2, v)$) distributions respectively. Except they're sampling distributions of variance rather than mean (for small samples, before all distributions approach normal).

So I have written this note that & I want to know if my understanding & notation is correct:
[image]

P.S. Unsure if I've got Degrees of Freedom (v and n parameters) right.

Comment: Mathematica shows your conjecture is not correct? Or you can reference to this page ([Univariate Distribution Relationships](https://www.math.wm.edu/~leemis/chart/UDR/UDR.html))? ```
PDF[ChiSquareDistribution[n], x]
PDF[StudentTDistribution[\[Nu]], x] /. {\[Nu] -> n - 1} // FullSimplify
PDF[GammaDistribution[\[Theta], k], x]
PDF[StudentTDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma], \[Nu]], x] /. {\[Sigma] -> Sqrt[\[Theta]/2], \[Nu] -> (2*k - 1)}
```

Comment: Please explain your notation: otherwise, we have no basis to assess whether it might be correct or not.

Comment: @whuber Is it the $lst(\mu, \sigma, v)$ & $\Gamma(\theta, k)$ that are confusing?

Comment: @whuber Or is it the equal signs inside the function arguments? Sometimes I embed equations in strange places as a reminder that either expression is valid in a certain place.

Comment: @138Aspen could you elaborate?

Comment: What is $\bar Y_0$?  What does "$lst$" refer to?  (A location-scale distribution is not determined by just three parameters!)  What is $\bar Y_\sigma$?  What do you mean by "is to"?   What is $s_{Y_0}^2$?  Because any reasonable guess I can make will render most of your equations false, I don't want to guess about anything.

Comment: @Whuber $lst$ is [location-scale-t distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution), wikipedia says it has 3 params. And "is to" doesn't mean anything rigorous I was just trying to make an analogy since it seems  student's-$t$ and $\chi^2$ distributions are sampling distributions of the mean and standard deviation respectively (when sampling from standard normal). And the other two distributions represent the case when sampling from different normal distributions.

Comment: @whuber Regarding all of your other questions please re-read the latex, I updated it for clarity.

Comment: Thank you.  Please note that the sample mean does not have a $t$ distribution, the sample variance does not have $n$ degrees of freedom, and "$lst$" is meaningless.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for corrections. Could you elaborate about the first & last points?

Comment: The sample mean is normal distributed. The t-distribution is the distribution for the sample mean divided by the sample standard deviation (with some scale factor). If you have no standard normal distributed variables then this becomes a scaled non-central t-distribution, and that is different from a scaled and shifted t-distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to know if my understanding & notation is correct:

It is incorrect.

- If the $Y_i$ are normal distributed, then the sample mean follows a normal distribution instead of t distribution.
- The sample variance is indeed gamma distributed.

The t-distribution is instead the distribution for the sample mean divided by the sample standard deviation (with some scale factor). If you have no standard normal distributed variables then this becomes a scaled non-central t-distribution, and that is different from a scaled and shifted t-distribution.

Regarding the notation the style could be improved. For example a phrase like "the sample mean of given Y variable" is not very clear. A variable is a sample of size one? Also, you write $s_Y^2:= \text{sample standard deviation}$, where the square is probably a typo.

---

You may find the maps for relationships of distributions interesting. See for instance: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relationships_among_probability_distributions

So for a sample of independent and identical normal distributed $Y_i \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ then

- if $\mu = 0$ and $\sigma = 1$

  $$\begin{array}{rcrcl}
  \bar{Y} &=& \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i &\sim & N(0,1/\sqrt{n})\\
  RSS & = & \sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i-\bar{Y})^2 &\sim& \chi^2_{n-1}\\
  &&\sqrt\frac{n-1}{n}\frac{\bar{Y}}{\sqrt{RSS}} &\sim& t_{n-1}
  \end{array}$$
- If $\sigma \neq 1$ then the scale of the first two distributions changes, and the special case of the $\chi^2$ distribution is a Gamma distribution. For the ratio nothing changes (it's the point of thee t-test, that it is independent of $\sigma$).
- If $\mu \neq 0$ then the last two distributions change into non-central distributions. Note that this  is different from a simple scaling.

Comment: Did you mean that if $\mu\neq 0$ rather than $\mu\neq 1$? For the last bullet.

Comment: @profPlum yes $\mu \neq 0$